# Jquery Data tables column reorder with requirejs not working?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, requirejs, datatables

I am using RequireJs to include "dataTables.colReorder.js" into my page but when I try to change column on a gridview, nothing is happening and also console not showing any error message. My requirejs code as follows:-

```
require.config({
    shim: {
      'angular-datatables': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'datatables'],
      },
      'reorder': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'datatables'],
      },
    },
    paths: {
      'jquery': '../lib/jquery.min',
      'datatables': '../lib/jquery.dataTables.min',
      'angular-datatables': '../lib/angular-datatables',
      'reorder': '../lib/dataTables.colReorder',
    },
    baseUrl: theme_base_url+'/js/'+module_id+'/',
    deps: ['app']
});

define(['app', 'reorder'], function (app) {

   ...

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. In Jquery data-table, "Column reorder" extension is already defined as RequireJs AMD mobule with name as "datatables-colreorder" in its library. So I just replaced my "reorder" name to "datatables-colreorder" name in "main.js" file. 
   In short, don't use your own name for "Column reorder" extension in "main.js" file when using RequireJs.